# How can I count the number of bytes that have been inserted in a sqlite3 field?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have a field that allows up to 40,000 `NVARCHAR (40000)` bytes to be inserted into.
I now want to determine the number of bytes which users are actually inserting into the field so I can get the max, average, etc.
What query would I use to do that?

Comment: Why care about _internal_ storage byte size? Or do you really mean `NVARCHAR (40000)` means 40000 bytes, not 40000 (Unicode) characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's suppose the name of your table is `target` and the name of your field is `data`.

The following query will do this for you:

```
select length(data) from target;
```

The sqlite3 [`length()` function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#length) returns the number of bytes in a field.

**NOTE**: This function actually returns the number of characters (not bytes) so this value could be different than expected in MBCS (multi-byte char systems).

**Extra**

I had inserted two emoji chars into my table and tested this.
[image: emoji and length function]

Comment: I was calculating like that already but not quite sure about it. It turns out it's quite accurate. My db is 25MB, counting the one field with all the data like this: select sum(length(data) )  / 1000000 as total from target gives me exactly 25MB

Comment: Yeah, it's quite accurate.  I'm not sure why people were bent of shape by my original question.  I was allowing 40,000 characters but was curious if anyone was actually storing that much data or if it was a lot smaller.